# I want to multiply column row strings n number of times

Tags: python, pandas

Input

```
columnheader 
Test
Hello
World
```

Outpt

```
columnheader 
Test, Test 
Hello, Hello
World, World

df.iloc[:, [1]] = df.iloc[:, [1]].apply(lambda x : x ", " + x)
```

This works but I want to use n number of repeat rather than manually

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One idea is use `join` with repeat values in list, for seelct second column use [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) without nested `[]` for select `Series`:

```
N = 3
#selecting by position
df.iloc[:, 1] = df.iloc[:, 1].apply(lambda x: ', '.join([str(x)] * N))
#selecting by column name
df['columnheader'] = df['columnheader'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join([str(x)] * N))
print (df)
          columnheader
0     Test, Test, Test
1  Hello, Hello, Hello
2  World, World, World
```

Or add separator, repeat by [`Series.mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mul.html) and last remove separator from right side by indexing (it is better for avoid `strip` - it should also remove separator if end in column `columnheader`):

```
N = 3
sep = ', '
#selecting by position
df.iloc[:, 1] = df.iloc[:, 1].astype(str).add(sep).mul(N).str[:-len(sep)]
#selecting by column name
df['columnheader'] = df['columnheader'].astype(str).add(sep).mul(N).str[:-len(sep)]
print (df)
          columnheader
0     Test, Test, Test
1  Hello, Hello, Hello
2  World, World, World
```

Comment: What is the `1` that you have as second argument to `apply`? It looks like it should be a boolean, so I guess an int would work but is more opaque.

Comment: I'm getting ' sequence item = 0: expected str instance, Series found. I added `df['columnheader'] = df['columnheader'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(str([x]) * N), axis=1)` still not working

Comment: @Arron - Meal culpa! `axis=1` is wrong, has to be removed.

Comment: @alani - OOPs, it has to be removed.

Comment: Still getting `sequence item = 0: expected str instance, Series found` error

Comment: @Arron - Can you try `df['columnheader'] = df['columnheader'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join([str(x)] * N))` ?

Comment: @jezrael Fair enough. The second argument seemed to be `convert_dtype` according to the docstring.

Comment: @Arron - Edited answer with `iloc`

Comment: Had to add astype(str) to your second idea. Working now thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A combination of [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) and [`join`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_join.asp) gives the desired output:

```
n=3 #number of times string has to multiplied
df['columnheader'] = df['columnheader'].map(lambda x : ', '.join([str(elem) for elem in [str(x)]*n]))
print(df)
```

**Output**:

```
          columnheader
0     Test, Test, Test
1  Hello, Hello, Hello
2  World, World, World
```